# Is it possible to open a file locally and push it to a remote host using ansible?

Tags: ansible

I wondering if is possible to do that, since I need to run a ios command inside a switch to test my master/backup environment.

The copy of a command was made like bellow:

```
tasks:

- name: capturing the command "show ip int br" on {{ inventory_hostname }}
  ios_command: 
    commands: 
      - sh ip int br | i up
    provider: "{{ cli }}"
  register: result
  tags: inft
- debug: var=result
  tags: result_debug


- name: copy interface status up to a temp file
  copy:
    content: "{{ result.stdout[0] }}"
    dest: "~/ANSIBLE/{{ inventory_hostname }}.cfg"
  tags: copy
```

Here is the file's output.

```
FastEthernet0/0            169.255.0.1     YES NVRAM  up                    up      
FastEthernet1/1            unassigned      YES unset  up                    up      
FastEthernet1/6            unassigned      YES unset  up                    up      
FastEthernet1/10           unassigned      YES unset  up                    up      
Vlan1                      unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up
```

After capturing the command, I need to open the file, read it line by line and run the ios command "shutdown" like this:

```
interface FastEthernet0/0
shutdown

interface FastEthernet0/1
shutdown
```

I was looking for the "script" and "expect" command, but none of my attempts work well.

Comment: Do you need to capture to file? Would it be enough to iterate the up interfaces and shut them down in place without first creating the file? Do you intend to shut down all interfaces including Vlan1?

Comment: @jscott Yes indeed. It's necessary because after shutdown the interfaces, I should bring it back after a lot of tests, using another ansible-playbook. The output.log will serves like a new "input" to do this new task to run the command "no shutdown".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using "with_file", registering the content of item.results[0].item and pushing it to the device like below:

```
 - name: Looping file
   debug:
     msg: "{{ item }}"
   register: items
   with_file:
     - ~/ANSIBLE/{{ inventory_hostname }}.cfg
 - debug: var=items.results[0].item


 - name: Applying The Shutdown Template
   ios_config:
     lines:
       - "{{ items.results[0].item }}"
     provider: "{{cli}}"
   register: shut
```

running the playbook:

```
TASK [Looping file] *******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [169.255.0.1] => (item=interface FastEthernet1/0 
shutdown
interface FastEthernet1/1 
shutdown
interface FastEthernet1/3 
shutdown
interface FastEthernet1/4 
shutdown
interface FastEthernet1/5 
shutdown
interface FastEthernet1/6 
shutdown) => {
"item": "interface FastEthernet1/0 \nshutdown\ninterface FastEthernet1/1       \nshutdown\ninterface FastEthernet1/3 \nshutdown\ninterface FastEthernet1/4 \nshutdown\ninterface FastEthernet1/5 \nshutdown\ninterface FastEthernet1/6 \nshutdown", 
"msg": "interface FastEthernet1/0 \nshutdown\ninterface FastEthernet1/1 \nshutdown\ninterface FastEthernet1/3 \nshutdown\ninterface FastEthernet1/4 \nshutdown\ninterface FastEthernet1/5 \nshutdown\ninterface FastEthernet1/6 \nshutdown"
}

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [169.255.0.1] => {
"items.results[0].item": "interface FastEthernet1/0 \nshutdown\ninterface FastEthernet1/1 \nshutdown\ninterface FastEthernet1/3 \nshutdown\ninterface FastEthernet1/4 \nshutdown\ninterface FastEthernet1/5 \nshutdown\ninterface FastEthernet1/6 \nshutdown"
}

TASK [Applying The Shutdown Template] *************************************************************************************************************
changed: [169.255.0.1]

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [169.255.0.1] => {
"shut1": {
    "banners": {}, 
    "changed": true, 
    "commands": [
        "interface FastEthernet1/0 ", 
        "shutdown", 
        "interface FastEthernet1/1 ", 
        "shutdown", 
        "interface FastEthernet1/3 ", 
        "shutdown", 
        "interface FastEthernet1/4 ", 
        "shutdown", 
        "interface FastEthernet1/5 ", 
        "shutdown", 
        "interface FastEthernet1/6 ", 
        "shutdown"
    ], 
    "updates": [
        "interface FastEthernet1/0 ", 
        "shutdown", 
        "interface FastEthernet1/1 ", 
        "shutdown", 
        "interface FastEthernet1/3 ", 
        "shutdown", 
        "interface FastEthernet1/4 ", 
        "shutdown", 
        "interface FastEthernet1/5 ", 
        "shutdown", 
        "interface FastEthernet1/6 ", 
        "shutdown"
    ]
}
}


 PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************
169.255.0.1                : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 0):

[with_lines](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-the-results-of-a-program-execution) is what you are looking for. It iterates through each line of the output of a program execution.

```
- shell: interface {{ item }} && shutdown
  with_lines: awk '{print $1}' ~/ANSIBLE/{{ inventory_hostname }}.cfg
```

The example above uses `awk` to print the first column of the file content.

Comment: Sr. Chris Lam, it might work. I'm going to test and I'll post the results in a couple of hours. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mr. Chris Lam, I so sorry for my tardiness, but I was occupied with a lot of projects and just for today I retook this subject.